# Injecting and using Http Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have a service class that should call an api and return the results:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import { Inject} from 'angular2/di';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

var httpMap = new WeakMap<ScheduleService, Http>();
export class ScheduleService {
    meetings: Array<any>;
    http: any;

    constructor(@Inject(Http) http:Http){
        httpMap.set(this, http);
        this.http = http;

        //http.get('/api/sample')
        //   .map(response => response.json())
        //   .subscribe(data => {
        //      this.serverData = data;
        //      });
    }

    getMeetings(){
        var path = '/api/meetings/';
        return httpMap.get(this).get(path);
    }

}
```

The service class is being called and injected correctly. The issue I am having is that when ever I call the `getMeetings` method it never makes the request to `/api/meetings`. If you guys notice in the constructor there is a `get` request to `/api/sample` that works perfectly if I uncomment it and run the program I check my `network` tab and I can see the request was made.

Comment: My knowledge about weak references is really poor, so I couldn't answer why in that way is not working, so, why don't you just use `this.http` in your `getMeetings()` method?

Comment: @EricMartinez Its essentially the same thing. I was just looking at a few blogs that were doing the mapping I just thought it looked dirty so I tried setting it as a property to the object to see if it worked and it did

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `http.get(path)` doesn't send off a request unless you call `http.get(path).subscribe();` even if you don't do anything with the response.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/b1fxoIUy31EHTC84U344?p=preview

In the Plunker, open the network view in the console and click the **With Subscribe** / **Without Subscribe** buttons for comparison.

Comment: Observables are lazy and don't do anything before `subscribe()` or `toPromise()` is called.